# swift vapor build(Building Project) will never ending and getting warning 'it's just not linked'

Tags: swift, vapor, vapor-cli

I have installed vapor on my mac and when trying to build project, it will never ending.

I am getting waring when trying to install again like below (brew install qutheory/tap/vapor)

```
Warning: qutheory/tap/vapor-0.4.1 already installed, it's just not linked.
```

and below is my running console output.

```
MAC-mini-A:vapor-docker22 mac$ vapor build
Fetching Dependencies [Done]
Building Project [ •                       ]
```

The last building project step will never ending.

.

Edit:

Building with Xcode works good, but I want to do with 'vapor build' command not from Xcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Homebrew install is very out of date. Use the installation instructions at https://vapor.github.io/documentation/getting-started/install-toolbox.html for a successful installation of the current version of Vapor.